# error en METRIC.EB Error in .local(x, …) : RasterLayer has no NA cells (for which to compute a distance)

Tags: r, raster

I am using my own data and am able to read both my original landsat image and the surface reflectance image with my area of interests (aoi). I get the following error when I use this code.

```
Energy.Balance <- METRIC.EB(
                     image.DN = image, 
                     image.SR = image.SR, 
                     plain=TRUE, 
                     aoi=aoi, 
                     n = 5, 
                     WeatherStation= ws, 
                     ETp.coef = 1.2, 
                     sat="L8", 
                     alb.coeff ="Olmedo",
                     LST.method = "SW", 
                     LAI.method = "metric2010", 
                     Z.om.ws = 0.03, 
                     MTL = MTLfile
                  )
```

> Error in .local(x, ...) : 
>     RasterLayer has no NA cells (for which to compute a distance)

When added:  `anchors.method ="flexible",  plain = TRUE`  to function `METRIC.EB()`

> ```
> Error in METRIC.EB(image.DN = image, image.SR = image.SR, plain = TRUE,  : 
>   formal argument "plain" matched by multiple actual arguments
> In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
> Warning messages:
> 1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>   display list redraw incomplete
> 2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
> 3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
> 4: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>   display list redraw incomplete
> 5: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
> 6: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
> 7: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>   display list redraw incomplete
> 8: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
> 9: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
> 10: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>   display list redraw incomplete
> 11: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>   invalid graphics state
> 12: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>   invalid graphics state
> ```

Comment: There seems to be a clear error message: `RasterLayer has no NA cells`?

Comment: That second error you got because you already have `plain=TRUE` (as 3rd argument)